# "Are you sure sure" — is this repetition grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, repetition

A typical conversation among members of my age demographic could go like this:

> Person 1: Did you know that x > y?!?
>
> Person 2: Are you sure?
>
> Person 1: Yeah, I'm sure.
>
> Person 2: Are you *sure* sure?

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: In my experience, someone would say "Are you sure you're sure?" rather than "Are you sure sure?".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think "grammatically correct" is really a meaningful issue in respect of this relatively common spoken usage - but if I have to have an opinion, I'd say it's valid but informal.

In general, to be *a [noun] noun]*, or be *[adjective] [adjective]* is simply an informal way of adding emphasis.

Often it's because the word being repeated has acquired multiple shades of meaning - arguably in OP's example the word *sure* can mean anything from *"Okay, I guess so"* to *"I would stake my life on it"*. The repetition is intended to focus attention on the *primary* meaning (certainty).

Comment: This is a grammatical process called [contrastive focus reduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_focus_reduplication). It's rare but grammatically valid in casual spoken English. (In many languages reduplication of various sorts is a common grammatical process, indicating that it is a normal product of how we think and (ab)use language.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Hmm. Doesn't look like a useful subclassification to me. *"Yummy Yummy yummy! I got room in my tummy!"*. Sure, sure, you can name anything - but what does that mean.

Comment: That's rhyming reduplication and isn't particularly interesting. Contrastive focus reduplication is *way* cooler. (My intention was only to provide more information for the curious. Also, to confirm that it's "valid but informal". As you were! ;)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Yeah, yeah. Like I say - Hmm. Repeating a word to indicate that your intended meaning is the *standard* meaning for that word doesn't seem to me inherently more interesting than repeating it to emphasise/stress a meaning which was never in doubt. Besides which, I think that second purpose applies in OP's case, so it doesn't seem to fit [this definition](http://www.iranianlinguistics.org/papers/salad-salad.pdf) anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Modern slang in North America (it doesn't seem to be restricted to a single age group) doubles a word to indicate emphasis, or in some cases that it's "really" whatever the word is - either that it truly literally is, that it is some sort of examplar of the word, or that it is a lot of whatever the word indicates.

- Joe and Sue are coming as a couple, but they're not a couple-couple.
- I told him I was flexible and now he thinks I'm flexible-flexible.
- I have to do some work but it's not work-work, I'm just booking some plane tickets

Language Log has quite a few mentions of this. Try http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3286 ,  http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004591.html and http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004594.html for starters - they have links to research papers, and/or comics. Can't lose, really.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with both FumbleFingers and Kate Gregory.

However, in this particular case, it seems to me that the sentence actually implies: "Are you sure [that you are] sure?". If the dropped words are correctly understood, the sentence makes perfect sense. It is not merely adding emphasis.

Grammar may not allow dropping words arbitrarily, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct in that it is understood and a recognizable part of speech. I would consider it slang but whether or not slang is correct, that's a question for endless debate. I do disagree with the idea that this emphasis is only used on nouns as one of the most common use cases I am aware of is for emphasizing a verb.

> Yeah, I like Susie but I don't *like* like her.

I'm not sure of the correct way this is written, probably because it is rarely written. (like like, like-like, *like* like, etc...)

Comment: Most people mean by 'correct' as what their teacher in high school would allow. So the reduplication is not particularly formal and you'd lose your job as a journalist if you used it. Just so that non-native speakers can understand what's going on, native speakers will still use this pattern informally (in this very particular way).