# Audio database is recorded under * conditions

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe a recorded speech database in an academic paper. It has been recorded via telephone. People call from their home / workplace, but not under *very* noisy conditions. Usual environmental noises (somebody talking behind, vehicular noise etc.) are present. I thought of describing it as "*the database is recorded under **realistic** conditions*". What are some better alternatives for the word **realistic**, if any?

Comment: Everyday?  Natural?

Comment: In the video biz it's called "wild sound" or "wild audio".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such circumstances are usually called [real-world conditions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22real%20world%20conditions%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (i.e. - not [controlled conditions](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under%20controlled%20conditions&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)).

Only my own opinion, but personally I think OP's suggested *"**realistic** conditions"* implies *controlled, artificial* conditions - although specifically designed to **mimic** real-world conditions, there's always a chance the testers either failed to set things up as they intended, or were unaware of some crucial aspect of the ["real real"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50060/are-you-sure-sure-is-this-repetition-grammatically-correct) world.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of this aspect. Basically you opine that **realistic** implies *less real* than plain **real**.

Comment: @user13107: That's certainly my opinion, yes. You can make a *realistic copy* of something, but unless you want to get involved in the metaphysical/philosophical implications of [fungibility](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/30313/2637), it doesn't make much sense to speak of a *real copy*.

Answer (score 4):

You might say under *[existing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/existing#Adjective)* conditions, or *[imperfect](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imperfect#Adjective), [uncontrolled](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncontrolled#Adjective), [run of the mill](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/run-of-the-mill#Adjective), [flawed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flawed#Adjective), as-found, [ordinary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ordinary#Adjective), [mediocre](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mediocre#Adjective)*.  Cornbread ninja's suggestion of *[everyday](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everyday?rdfrom=Everyday#Adjective)* also is good, and its definition leads to *[commonplace](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commonplace#Adjective)* (as well as  *ordinary*, already suggested).

Comment: Thanks, just a doubt, would 'run  of the mill' work in an academic paper setting? Right now I'm trying to google up all the suggested alternatives to see how they have been used by people in the literature.

Comment: @user13107, 'run of the mill' may be ok in some academic papers but is less likely than the other terms.  Using several words together, at least upon first mention, might be best.  Eg, "... recorded under existing, everyday, less-than-pristine conditions".

Answer (score 2):

I have often heard the background sounds referred to as the *ambient* noise.

[What is Ambient Noise?](http://peripherals.about.com/od/glossaryofpcterms/g/What-Is-Ambient-Noise.htm)

"Ambient conditions" seems to have more use on the Web as referring to weather, but if you told me that whatever I was about to listen to was recorded under ambient conditons I would be expecting background noise.