# "Sure to do something?" — is it correct?

Tags: questions

Is the question "Sure to delete selected elements?" correct? I have seen this many times. Can I use such questions in this form on a website? Does it make a difference to place it on a website?
I have found this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50060/are-you-sure-sure-is-this-repetition-grammatically-correct) but it is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Most sites I use ask, *Are you sure you want to...*? Is this the meaning of your phrase?

Comment: From WHAT language is this translated?

Comment: I think this is Off Topic General Reference for ELU, but could be okay on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). @itsols: I'm accustomed to seeing OP's construction (usually preceded by *"Are you..."* in ***German*** software. I don't know German well enough to know if this is because the "translated" equivalent is a valid grammatical form in that language.

Comment: Translation from other languages to English (including proofreading or criticism of translations) is off topic. If the question is not about translation, but is actually a question about the English language, please clarify what specifically is being asked about.

Comment: Questions which are essentially "is this correct" are out of scope. They are a request for proofreading. Even though you have taken the translation aspect out of the question, this is still a request for proofreading. For more information on the purpose of this site and its scope, please see the [help]. As @FumbleFingers pointed out this seems like a great question to ask at [ell.se] and I echo his suggestion that you ask there.

Answer (score 2):

Questions (interrogative sentences) in English do not generally begin with an adjective, except informally:

> Sure you want to quit now?

Which is shorthand for:

> Are you sure [that] you want to quit now?

However, the real problem is that the sentence doesn't mean what the writer thinks it does. Consider this:

> Are you sure to leave?

This is a slightly archaic way of saying "will you definitely be going?", which is not at all the same question as "do you want to leave?".

Answer (score 2):

A more likely correct translation would be "OK to delete selected elements?" as a confirmation of whether or not you really want to delete those things.

"OK" and "Sure" can be used somewhat interchangeably as the answer to a question seeking confirmation:

> Can I do something?
>
> - OK.
> - Sure.

But they are not interchangeable when you are *asking* the question:

> - Is it OK if I do something?
> - <sup>??</sup>Is it sure if I do something?

When asking permission to proceed, it's common to leave out the "Is it", so you end up with the form:

> OK to delete selected elements?